# Add a new collection inside a custom configuration section

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a custom configuration section and I need to add a new NameValue thing to it

Here is the hierarchy

```
 -organizationConfigurations
 |-organizationConfigSelector
 |-specificConfigurations
  |-organizationConfig
```

Now I need to add an element called *skipLanguages* to *organizationConfig* and this is just a simple collection element that is going to just hold strings. Here is the XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<matcher type="Host" match="HORNET" serviceName="config-hornet"/>
<matcher type="Parameter" match="VTDEV" serviceName="config-test-server"/>
```

```
<organizationConfig name="config-hornet">
  <add name="Organization_Identifier" value="SampleOrg"/>

  <add name="Allow_SelfRegistration" value="true"/>

  <add name="ApplicationSelector" value=""/>
  <add name="RegistrationSelector" value=""/>

  <add name="EnrollPinValidity" value="00.00:01:00"/>
  <add name="EnrollIncoming" value="0123456789"/>
  <add name="EnrollOutgoing" value="PIN"/>

  <add name="EnrollmentLockout" value="00.00:01:00"/>
  <add name="PinLockout" value="00.00:00:30"/>

  <skipLanguages>
    <add name="en"/>
    <add name="ur-UR" />
  </skipLanguages>

  <add name="Menu_Hide_Details" value="false"/>
  <add name="International_Format_Example" value="00971559559123"/>

  <add name="Service_Operator_Name" value="admin"/>
  <add name="Service_Operator_Password" value="admin"/>

  <add name="Service_Operator_Address_VTadp" value="https://hornet.org.com:1337/main/basicHttp"/>
  <add name="Service_Operator_Address_Admin" value="https://hornet.org.com:1337/Admn/basicHttp"/>
  <add name="Service_Operator_Address_PWR" value="https://hornet.org.com:1337/PWR/basicHttp"/>

</organizationConfig>
```

The classes for *specificConfigurations* & *organizationConfig* & are:

```
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(OrganizationConfig), AddItemName = "organizationConfig")]
    public class SpecificConfigurations : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        #region Indexer
        public OrganizationConfig this[int index]
        {
            get { return BaseGet(index) as OrganizationConfig; }
            set
            {
                if (BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }

                BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Method(s)
        public OrganizationConfig GetServiceInfo(string serviceName)
        {
            return BaseGet(serviceName) as OrganizationConfig;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overridden Method(s)
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new OrganizationConfig();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((OrganizationConfig)element).Name;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class OrganizationConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        #region Configuration Properties
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this["name"] as string; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public NameValueConfigurationCollection Settings
        {
            get { return (NameValueConfigurationCollection)base[""]; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: For the time being, I added SkipLanguages as a NameValue pair with value as a semi-colon separated string with languages to hide/block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I added SkipLanguages as a NameValue pair with value as a semi-colon separated string with languages to hide/block. Apparently, this worked very well and was also accepted by lead. So, I'm completing this question with my own answer.